# What exception to raise for duplicate instance Django

Tags: django

I have a `util` method called `add_user`, which takes in an email and password and creates a user. First, it checks if that user already exists though:

```
if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
    # raise some exception
```

**What kind of exception should I raise here?** Thanks!!

Comment: If this is in a form, or in the `clean` method of a model, likely a `ValidationError`.

Comment: But if `email` is `unique=True`, then Django will *automatically* do that for you.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it is not part of a form, and I can't make `unique=True` on the User, so it wouldn't happen automatically. What should I do in this case? Thanks@

Comment: @JJT How are you calling the method? You should raise an exception that the calling code can handle appropriately

Comment: @IainShelvington There is a view that renders a list of all users and there is a button on that page that allows for adding users. In that view, I check if that button was pressed (a POST to that view) then call this util method to add a user. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

if question is about raising exception then use `ObjectDoesNotExist` from `django.core.exceptions`, i think you should create [custom objects manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/managers/) for User Model and use custom exception inheriting `ObjectDoesNotExist`.
For example,

```
class EmailAlreadyExists(ObjectDoesNotExist):
       pass
```

Or Another way is to create class method:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

 @classmethod
 def create_user(cls, email):
    if objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        raise EmailAlreadyExists()
```

above code may not work such as i don't or forgot if we need to pass some params to `EmailAlreadyExists` because its being inherited from `ObjectDoesNotExist`.

Best approach is to create custom objects manager for `User` and validate everything there. By default, Django already taking take care of email field for users.